# WCF Ria Services number sequence generator

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, generator, sequence, wcf-ria-services

I need RIA Service method to return next free integer (stored in database). (for purpose of online payment transaction number)

How to achieve this efficiently and reliably?

I could have created an empty table (with ID only) and let EF do the rest for me, but Im sure its a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that practice is fairly typical.

You can also just request that maximum amount of a number and insert one higher - in case a competing request tries to insert the same number, the database will refuse one of them if you have a unique key on the number.

That way is a bit more flexible and probably easier to maintain. The collisions will be very rare for most applications, and all the user has to do is to retry.